# CSRF across multiple applications/services

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, angular, csrf

I have 2 applications under the same domain, 1 running from a PHP 5.6 server with Laravel 5.2 backend & Angular2 frontend, and the other with a custom framework on a PHP 5.3 server with flat javascript frontend. In each application I have a csrf token. The older server (5.3) has a custom csrf generator, but the laravel one uses laravel's VerifyCsrfToken.php middleware.

I occasionally need to call an old API from the angular2 frontend, but the csrf tokens do not match. How do I implement a custom csrf token generator in laravel?

Comment: The token don't match in the Laravel or other framework?

Comment: The laravel csrf matches the angular2 csrf, but both of those need to match the other framework's csrf

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `OldTokenClass`and pass the token to all your views. However, it's hard for me to speculate on what should be in `OldTokenClass` with the information you provide. Essentially, you should be able to generate or obtain the old app token from that class.

Something like

```
//Route
use App\Service\OldTokenClass;

view()->composer('*', function ($view) {
    $tokenGen =  new OldTokenClass();

    return $view->with('old_crsf_token', $tokenGen->get());

});
```

Then in your view layout you could do something like

```
    <meta name="old-csrf-token" content="{{$old_crsf_token}}">
```

and use it with angular.